# Are questions regarding pronunciation on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947263/how-to-pronounce-intptr) question which asks about the pronunciation of `IntPtr`, is this a valid question for Stack Overflow?

My understanding is that SO is meant to answer questions that help to solve issues of a technical nature that are blocking further progress for the OP. I would argue that it doesn't fit any of the 4 conditions mentioned in the FAQ, but the fact that this question already has 2 reopen votes makes me very unsure of my understanding.

Comment: I feel like there's some backlash against strict adherence to the  mission statement / site guidelines that crops up from time to time.

Comment: A lot of users will reopen anything regardless of how far out of scope a question is

Comment: [Screenshot of the question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CUFjg.png). Looks like there are some "How do you pronounce this?" questions laying around that need to be close and deleted... Because they're amusing and demonstrate why these type of questions are off-topic, [here is a screenshot of the comments as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmEox.png).

Comment: I've done my bit before too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726131/where-did-the-term-roll-a-patch-come-from

Comment: @shree.pat18 that's not the same kind of question, though it too may also be off-topic perhaps, but for a different reason.

Comment: @Cupcake Could you elaborate on that please? Unless you are saying that one is about etymology, in which case I agree.

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes, it's about etymology, which, like I said, may or may not be off-topic for different reasons than because of pronounciation.

Comment: Asks a question that is only answerable by opinions.  Denies this, wants links to authoritative sources.  Twice as off topic.

Comment: see [Where is an appropriate place to ask the proper pronounciation of a programming term?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216429/165773) at MSE

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Questions about how to pronounce technical terms should most definitely be **off-topic** on Stack Overflow, because they're *always* opinion-based (and the stuff of *endless* discussion and back-and-forth arguing that *goes nowhere*).

Even when there's an "official" way to pronounce a term, you'll find developers who just refuse to adopt the official standard.

Example: do you pronounce "SQL" as "S.Q.L." or "sequel"? I know developers who will *refuse* to use the former, even though it's now the "official" pronunciation. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Standardization):

> The original standard declared that the official pronunciation for "SQL" was an initialism: /ˈɛs kjuː ˈɛl/ ("es queue el").<sup>[[10](http://databases.about.com/od/sql/a/sqlfundamentals.htm)]</sup> Regardless, many English-speaking database professionals (including [Donald Chamberlin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Chamberlin) himself<sup>[[36](http://patorjk.com/blog/2012/01/26/pronouncing-sql-s-q-l-or-sequel/)]</sup>) use the acronym-like pronunciation of /ˈsiːkwəl/ ("sequel"),<sup>[37]</sup> mirroring the language's pre-release development name of "SEQUEL".<sup>[13][[14](http://www.mhprofessional.com/product.php?cat=112&isbn=0071469605)]</sup>

Comment: You seem to contradict yourself a little here. It's not necessarily opinion-based since you can sometimes find an official source. Proving the absence of fact that makes the question opinion-based can be difficult. Whether it becomes opinion based because a number of developers don't adopt the official standard doesn't necessarily makes this opinion-based: I'm sure there are many developers who don't program such and such correctly according to the official API/doc, yet there can still be an official guideline as to how to do something.

Comment: @Bruno: if the "official source" doesn't mirror actual usage and people get angry about the fact, it's opinion-based flamebait even if one side can produce citations.

Comment: @Bruno an argument can be made that such questions are off-topic anyways, because they're not really programming problems. Standards and conventions are more in the domain of [programmers.se], but I have my doubts that such a question would fair well over there either.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point.

Comment: Couldn't disagree with this more. `even though it's now the "official" pronunciation` So you're acknowledging that there's an official pronunciation (i.e. such questions have answers), but you just don't think people should talk about it? Strange.

Comment: @Cupcake your point about opinion based makes these _very_ poor fit for Programmers as well - subject for being quickly voted down and closed over there, see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**