# May I ask a vocabulary question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

I am looking for a technical term related to programming.

I thought I read once that word and I can not remember, but I am not sure that there really is a expression for that.

Can I ask this kind of question on Stack Overflow?

---

The question I would like to ask is this one:

> Is there a word for the act of importing a library to use only one
>   function, while there were native and standard ways to solve the
>   problem without having to overload its program by using an heavy
>   import?
>
> This corresponds to slightly facilitate the work, but for a single use
>   and this leads to an heavier program.

Comment: If you tighten up what you mean by "done without", I could see this as being on topic either here *or* on Programmers.

Comment: I believe there's a canonical dupe for this, but it lives on [meta.se] now.  The consensus, essentially, was that trivia questions weren't on topic.  No guessing or remembering something or other.  This standard isn't applied globally to the network, of course.  Chat would be a good place for something like this.

Comment: @Makoto I tried to better explain what I mean by "done without".

Comment: Nobody has taken the bait and just posted the word yet! Excellent restraint, people!

Comment: Suggestions to improve: 1) Consider explaining the purpose of the word; IOW, examples of sentences where you would use this word. 2) Instead of "Is there a word" ask "What is the word"; it seems minor, but the former can be answered with "yes" or "No", whereas the latter one must provide a word. 3) I don't know of any word which fits the bill :)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266739/are-questions-regarding-pronunciation-on-topic-for-stack-overflow

Comment: @Mogsdad Perhaps because no one here knows what it is :). Time for the OP to go ask a linguist.

Comment: @Will [Questions about terminology related to computer programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142724/165773)

Comment: @Delgan, Actually you can ask your question on Quora.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably not.

Most questions regarding the English language belong on [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Based on the information provided, you should probably ask there.

Regarding your actual question, posed slightly differently it would fit on English.SE ("Word for using one thing of many...") but could fit on Programmers as well as the other answer suggests.

Comment: It is a word closely related to programming, would it not make more sense to ask the question to developers rather than linguists?

Comment: @Delgan Possibly... but you haven't posed the actual question. Its very hard to tell. **Generally**, I would pose a vocabulary question to a linguist.

Comment: I edited and provided the actual question.

Comment: @Delgan - I don't hang out much there but from what I've seen of their Hot Network Questions, The English Language and Usage folks seem to be *really* good at finding words. There's also over 180 questions in their [programming tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) so it wouldn't be the first time they've gotten a question about a technical term.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a good ice-breaker for [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com). Pick an open chat room for your language of choice, and have at it.

Comment: You're unlikely to get any answer to that question on chat.......

Comment: @Pacerier ... Which would explain why it's called **chat**, and not Q&A.  The OP did not ask where they would get an answer, rather if they could ask the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it would qualify here but it is hard to tell without seeing the proposed question.  As for whether it is on topic on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the short answer is that it is a [controversial, unsettled topic.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6582/88986) Read their [site guidelines carefully](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/88986) before posting a definition question there; low quality ones have [a strong chance of being downvoted and closed.](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6483/88986)

Comment: Relevant programmers guidance: [On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582/88986)

Comment: @durron597 thanks for the reference

Comment: I edited your post to reflect actual programmers policy, rather than leaving it as a "I don't know whether it is on topic"