# Why is this question closed for "There are either too many possible answers"?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

See:

[What does "CG" in CGGeometry, CGPoint, CGRect stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610813/what-does-cg-in-cggeometry-cgpoint-cgrect-stand-for)

This question only has 1 possible answer and that is **Core Graphics**. It's in Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html).

Shouldn't the question be reopened? Or is it that I am missing something?

The question is asked so that a developer would have better semantic understanding of what he is coding!

Comment: Comments [archived](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/117138/discussion-on-question-by-honey-why-is-this-question-closed-for-there-are-eithe).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [May I ask a vocabulary question on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299218/may-i-ask-a-vocabulary-question-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: That's... Not very similar at all @BSMP.

Comment: @Shog9 - You don't think "What does CG mean" is a vocabulary question?

Comment: Might wanna read past the title there, @BSMP. That question is more akin to [single word requests over on EL&U](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's definitely not too broad.

It might be argued that it's *too specific*, but there's no close reason for that nor do I have a good feel for what "too" would mean in that case; arguably the meaning of a naming convention for a major API is a *lot* more applicable than most of the questions that get asked here daily.

I reopened it. It may be re-closed; I'd be interested to hear others' feelings on the matter.

Comment: I can tell from experience that "what do these CG and NS prefixes mean" is one of the most popular first questions from new Mac and iOS developers. Now that Swift is cross-platform, knowing that some code they've found online needs Core Graphics to work could be pretty handy to a Linux Swift developer. Finally, Apple is [in the process of renaming a ton of this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326078/swift-3-ios-10-introduces-class-name-changes-how-to-handle-the-flood-of-potenti), so where an old prefix came from might help in code translation.

Comment: I am on the fence, because it seems there is a slippery slope here. Perhaps having just one of these around isn't problematic (although I am not sure why simply consulting wikipedia didn't suffice in this instance). Obligatory: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iuR7Q.png (sfw)

Comment: It's now closed again, but it has 2 reopen votes.

Comment: Eh... There are tons of these on SO already, @Travis. I've seen relatively few problems with them *when they're concrete questions* - subjective "what should I name this?" stuff is a different matter. Figuring out naming and terminology ends up being a pretty major stumbling block for folks, so having the information there probably leads to fewer stupid mistakes and fewer questions that could be solved by googling if only the proper terms were known.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen some too. Haven't gone looking for them or anything though so I am not sure of the overall amount. I have seen a decent amount of them removed too. Perhaps we need a RTFM exchange where users can ask what the manual means when it uses what some consider to be cryptic language.

Answer (score -42):

> Why is this question closed [...] ?

**Because is trivia.** Knowing the answer doesn't make you a better programmer, nor gives you a [solution to a problem](https://xkcd.com/979/), nor makes you better person, nor offers another perspective about a topic, etc. It offers no plus for anyone other than knowing it... and **you can't do anything productive with that knowledge** except annoy a couple of coworkers, in which case they may get suspicious that [you are a secret agent trying to sabotage the company](http://www.mintpressnews.com/declassified-cia-manual-shows-how-us-uses-bureaucracy-to-destabilize-governments/211894/) making people aware of trivialities.

Other reason why it should be closed is because you don't need to be a subject aware to answer these questions... I can know next to nothing about the language and I would be able to accurately answer the question nonetheless (and get craptons of votes in the process), but that doesn't mean that I'm a more useful community member, nor I'm expanding the wealth of knowledge available on the internet.

Comment: This is indeed potentially a reason to close the quesiton, but not as "too broad".

Comment: @Servy My answer was focusing in "why was this closed" not "why was this closed using *this* reason".

Comment: I disagree with "trivia doesn't make you a better programmer" and "you can't do anything productive with that knowledge". I always forgot how `cin` and `cout` were called until I was told they were `c-in` and `c-out`. Now the names seem obvious and I remember them.

Comment: Every language, framework etc. has its own little population of naming conventions. Some of them are pretty bad/sparely documented. Some of them even decide how the system reacts. As a beginner in a certain system it is a lot easier to read code if you know the meaning of the naming conventions and I would argue that you can't follow naming conventions properly if you don't understand them - which makes your code harder to read for others. So I don't think questions about naming conventions are trivia per se and in my opinion following conventions makes one indeed a better programmer.

Comment: @Rhayene This one in particular was evidently well documented, it is in the introduction.

Comment: @Braiam I wasn't aware your entire answer is only about this one question and not this kind of questions in general - as your second paragraph suggests. I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I still disagree that you can't do anything productive with the knowledge though.

Comment: As far as I know, it's still Stack Overflow's goal to answer every programming question imaginable, of which set this question is part of. That this requires a lot of content existing in online manuals and tutorials to also exist in the Stack Overflow database has never been an excuse to close questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster and that's why is dying... slowly but surely. BTW, when was the last time that you saw 3 interesting questions in a row?

Comment: I still vividly the very first time I asked why is the higher order function named `reduce`? It's not like I'm subtracting something. Then I got an answer that the reason is because: You're trying to iterate through an array an do some operation that _reduces_ the **n** elements of the array into a **1** unit/item. That helped me understand the usage of `reduce` 10X better. It was not trivial in any sense