# The [pronunciation] is all wrong!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I came across the [pronunciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation).

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

Well..yes. The description says:

> Questions about how to pronounce technical terms.

But these are Offtopic explicitly according to [Are questions regarding pronunciation on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266739/are-questions-regarding-pronunciation-on-topic-for-stack-overflow)

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
No as specified in previous point. Also Most of the questions are either entirely off topic (pronunciation of a term) or too broad like (creating a function/module) like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014308/unity-chinese-to-english-dictionary-with-pronunication-function).

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Yes

Comment: I agree with the answer on the linked meta; "How to pronounce term X" will just lead to an endless debate between people who speak English and Americans. I can phantom a use for the tag such as "I'm writing a speech-recognition system, how to deal with pronunciation differences?" or something, but am unsure whether that'd warrant a tag of its own.

Comment: Considering it's used on only __18__ questions, do we need to walk through the official burnination process, or can we just remove this?

Comment: "Pronunciation" might be appropriate in the question is about converting text to speech. If any of the questions is about that, I suggest editing the tag wiki instead. Otherwise... burninate.

Comment: Punny title proposal: The [pronunciation] is all wrong!

Comment: Considering the small amount of questions tagged, following a short [discussion in the SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41260244#41260244), the question tagged with this tag have been reviewed. All of them were either too broad, or opinion based, and could be closed. After closure, the tag has been edited out of the questions.