# Can we speak out against all the pronunciations?

Tags: discussion, clean-up

There appears to be community [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266739) that questions asking about pronunciations of technical programming terms is off-topic.

The [pronunciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) tag has also been [discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363417) before, and that tag has already been burninated (though there is still one question with that tag).

However, a simple search for the keywords [pronounce](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Newest&q=pronounce+is:question), and [pronunciation](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Newest&q=pronunciation+is:question) in the titles of questions yield on the order of 500 results each. A lot of them are exactly the kind of off-topic questions of the kind mentioned in the first linked post.

It seems to me that all those kinds of questions can be closed, and then deleted. Is this something that could be easily done by a moderator? If not, then some sort of concerted effort by users could be initiated, perhaps in certain chat rooms whose mandate is basically this sort of cleanup.

Do people think it's worth the effort to get rid of these questions, and if so, what is the most efficient way to achieve that? I'm looking for any feedback on how to solve this problem.

---

While I would like to address all these questions, there seem to be a few ways in which these questions could be divided. For example, this [list](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Apronounce+closed%3Ano) provided by @gnat covers only the subset of such questions that are currently open, and have the word "pronounce" in the title.

If we could tackle this subset independently, it would then allow us to focus our attention on whether those closed posts should be deleted, or in some cases [locked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587). I think the latter choice is unlikely to be necessary, but I'm open to the idea that a pronunciation question could be useful, if for some reason the pronunciation actually provides some insight into the technical term itself.

Comment: @KUMAR No, the [tag:pronunciation] tag has already been effectively removed. This is about pronunciation questions without that tag.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know these questions existed, I'm gunna have to go through all of them and see how many I agree with, first one in the pronunciation search? *"Which means it can't be Tea Kinter beacause the T and K are grouped together, it must be Teakay-inter."* - Yeah... I'm gunna have to disagree with that one... 1,423 results to go....

Comment: Gnat recommended a more targeted list, maybe you missed it: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Apronounce+closed%3Ano

Comment: Perhaps *"...* ***speak out against*** *all the pronunciations?"* (or similar - I am not sure if that [is idiomatic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak_out#Verb) or not (as a whole))?

Comment: How do you pronounce: *Save yourself - close them all*?

Comment: @TylerH Yes, I did see that list. But I don't see any reason (at least for this discussion) to constrain the scope. There may be different approaches for questions that are closed, versus those that are not, but I'd like to address all those questions as a whole here.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yeah, that scans, and I like it. I'm not used to posting on meta, so I'm not in the habit of being witty in the title. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @cigien Well, there's two problems: 1. much larger scope needs much larger buy-in from Meta. 2. not all the questions on the first list are going to be relevant... some will be perfectly fine... they will just happen to have the word 'pronounce' in a question or answer somewhere (aka 'false positives'). Even the second, much smaller list has a few false positives. Reducing the scope to a tighter list of criteria gives a more accurate look at the size of the problem and the amount of work required to tackle it.

Comment: @TylerH I see your point. I've edited the question to suggest breaking up the scope to make the problem solvable in pieces. Does the edit address your concerns? I haven't mentioned anything about false positives, since that's the only reason why this needs the community to look at the questions, instead of just a script to close/delete all of them.

Comment: Let's pronounce these questions to be closed. :)

Comment: I wonder if it's called sequel or es kju el. Which tag should I use? `sql`? `sequel`? both?

Comment: @BernhardBarker 25 questions you look at in that search by title "pronounce" are not worth checking anymore. Initially this search displayed 45 questions and all that were obviously worth closing are gone now. At current phase this cleanup focuses on the specific questions in the list maintained and updated in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402815/839601)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @TRiG I guess problem is solved already. Having less than 10K I can't see deleted questions but per my recollection initial list proposed for community review contained quite a bunch of _recent_ pronunciation questions that were posted despite prior community efforts to clean up this stuff from the site. Some (most?) of these seemed to be inspired by old inappropriate but popular questions ([broken windows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-windows)). In a week that passesd since this was posted these seem to be all gone

Answer (score 46):

Pronunciation is highly opinion based and subjective matter. I am strictly against allowing such questions.

I don't have to go far to look for reasons...

I am Delphi developer and Delphi developers still don't know how to pronounce Delphi... or should I say, we all know how to pronounce it, we just don't agree with the other side that pronounces it differently.

Del - fee or Del - fye that is the ultimate question.

To make situation more fun, it was US based company Borland that named their own product Delphi and most of their US based developers and officials are using wrong pronunciation Del - fye, when obviously correct one is Del - fee ;)

Ancient Greeks might have their view on the issue, too. [What’s the history of the pronunciation of Delphi?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32260/what-s-the-history-of-the-pronunciation-of-delphi)

Moral of the story, while communication is important, it is less important whether some pronunciation is right or wrong, as long as you understand each other.

We Delphi developers stick together even though we cannot even agree on our beloved language name.

Comment: "*Pronunciation is highly opinion based and subjective matter*" - I don't think so. Most can be solved with a look in the dictionary (even if that states multiple accepted pronunciations). Of course, that doesn't make such questions on-topic (rather, it's an off-topic request for a reference), but I disagree with your stance that they're *generally* opinion-based.

Comment: @Bergi so your solution would be to take the dictionary and incorporate every "official" (I guess I can call it official if it has a dictionary) dialect of English into a pronunciation guide? Can I pronounce it differently if I'm in New Zealand, or Scotland? What about "languages" without official writing, like Swiss German?

Comment: @Bergi: Dictionaries usually don't list technical terms or invented names for technologies.  And for instance, if you look up how to pronounce "latex" in a dictionary, what you get will not resemble the common pronunciations of LaTeX.

Comment: GIF vs. JIF comes to mind...

Comment: @smcs Java in my native language is pronounced Yava... not to mention that half of the letter named languages have different pronunciation comparing to English one.

Comment: @NateEldredge Wait, "LaTeX" isn't pronounced like the rubber?

Comment: @TylerH: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17502/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-tex-and-latex

Comment: @smcs Jif is something else entirely [(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX11P.jpg) [(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Orn.jpg)

Comment: @Mast Oh.. I always thought it tasted horrible on toast. Will try the first one now.. (I assume your comment was made in jest and that you're aware GIF is named after (1))

Comment: [The GIF controversy](https://twitter.com/IamPablo/status/1291233720804839424).

Comment: Other examples: SQL and [KiCad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KiCad).

Comment: Deno - [Ryan Dahl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryan_Dahl) invented a cool new tool but [can't work out himself how to pronounce it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gIiZfSbEAE&ab_channel=SitePen)

Comment: It's not pronunciation questions that should be banned,  it pronunciation of proper nouns. Technical terms aren't themselves a problem, it's just that most of them are proper nouns - GIF, Delphi, etc. Even place names like Birmingham or Cairo, are variable.

Comment: You've got one extended example, Delphi.  That doesn't rule out other cases where there may be a standard or recommended pronunciation. There are plenty of bigger problems than this but a question of the form "Is there a standard or recommended pronunciation for X?" allows the answer No -- and it allows the answer Yes when there is one -- and it allows people to ignore the question if they think it's trivial or silly. But wanting to ban other people discussing this if they find it worth discussing is a most disappointing stance. This doesn't have to be a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 43):

As someone who was unpersuaded of the wisdom of the original consensus, I'd suggest restraint here too.

I understand the rationale for being against these questions - they're often purely matters of opinion, and voting on answers may represent nothing but a popularity contest. But it doesn't seem to me that that's an *inevitable* consequence of a question being about terminology pronunciation. Many of these questions actually have an objective answer, insofar as the official documentation or standards specify how a term should be pronounced. Even when they don't and the proper pronunciation is contentious, sometimes notable public figures have opined on the matter, and an answer can at least strive to provide the reader with a neutral summary of the different positions. As such, I think these questions *can* be good, and they and their answers ought to be evaluated case by case rather than facing blanket closure and deletion.

Also, sometimes "pronunciation" questions are not really about spoken pronunciation per se as they are about what symbols are called; the asker just happens to have used the word "pronounced" instead of "called" or "named". Such questions are even more likely to have a single official answer.

Regardless of all the above, I also note that there really aren't that many of these questions. If we narrow your search down to only [questions with "pronounce" in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3apronounce), we find only 60, plus [another 99 for "pronunciation"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3apronounce). It looks to me like these are roughly equally split between terminology pronunciation questions and questions about dealing with text-to-speech and speech-to-text systems, leaving only a few dozen questions of the kind you're interested in cleaning up.

Of those, *some* are uncontroversially garbage, and if anyone wants to clean them up, then so be it... but there *are* a handful I might be inclined to defend. For instance, [How do I pronounce "=>" as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274022/1709587) has a sort-of official answer - the MSDN docs once specified both the formal name of `=>` and also how to pronounce an expression featuring it, and one of the answers quotes those docs. Personally that question therefore strikes me as useful, despite having also accrued some irritating opinionated answers, and I don't think it warrants deletion (and I respectfully disagree with those who previously voted to close it).

Comment: Note that naming/calling questions are off-topic and belong on, for example, EL&U. As such pronunciation questions also probably belong on that site, too. Even with "official things", it's like "gif". There's an official pronunciation but you'll still find plenty of people who pronounce it differently (and swear by it). Perhaps more important, a symbol/word/name, etc. being mis*pronounced in real life* has no bearing on whether it will run when *typed*. So I think such questions are not about programming insofar as the scope of SO goes, until we get languages/IDEs that convert speech to text.

Comment: *"Note that naming questions are off-topic and belong on, for example, EL&U."* - probably unsurprisingly, I disagree with this too, though even on that point I may be in the minority. Such questions can be critically important to know the answer to - you can't effectiively google for something if you don't know its name - and often have objective answers. It doesn't make any sense to me to disallow them. (And while I can't speak for their community, I can't imagine EL&U would welcome programmers posting questions about the names of operators.)

Comment: By naming questions, I mean mostly "what should I call/name this", not "what is this called".

Comment: I don't disagree that some pronunciations have an objective answer. I also think it's useful to know what notable public figures have said about these things. However, there are suitable forums for such discussions, such as Reddit or Quora, and I don't think SO is one of them.

Comment: Some might have an objective answer but...spoken human language being what it is will inevitably muck things up. Shining example is "SQL". You're supposed to pronounce it "sequel". Indeed, that literally used to be the name: SEQUEL which was then reworked into SQL. So, objectively, it's to be pronounced as the word. Yet, plenty of people pronounce the individual letters. I've been in many conversations where one person would say "sequel" the other "es qu el". Usually nobody minds - all parties know what the spoken term is about. Language drifted despite there being a "correct" pronunciation.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, but that's because both "sequel" and "S-Q-L" are prevalent. If you roll up with "Squickel", you're going to get either odd looks or blank confusion. -- I think the issues with these questions as treating them as asking about "The One True Correct Pronunciation", which is often an invitation to flame wars. Treating them as "how do I pronounce this such that I'm understood", where "both are fine" is a valid answer seems more sane to me. - And one which I feel should be on topic, as discussing code with your colleagues is an important part of programming.

Comment: "discussing code with your colleagues is an important part of programming" True. So is whether to use tabs or spaces, or to use Git Flow. The question is whether the discussion has to occur on Stack Overflow or not.

Comment: For the record, naming questions are off topic on ELU as well. See ELU meta for more information: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9607/191178.  (Some questions are not on topic anywhere on the SE network.)

Comment: @R.M. Even worse, a not-inconsequential amount of people pronounce it "SQuirreL"...

Comment: Thanks for voicing this, I completely agree. Pronunciation can be important for clear communication in some settings. In others, "there are two pronounciations" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Note that [How do I pronounce “=>” as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022) has been locked now.

Comment: @TylerH "a symbol/word/name, etc. being mispronounced in real life has no bearing on whether it will run when typed" - true, but programming involves researching things online and communicating with other programmers. For symbols at least, both of those can be significantly more difficult/embarrassing if you don't even know the name of the thing you're trying to reference. You could probably extend this argument to general English, interpersonal skills or hardware questions, but the difference is these are unmistakably about programming and don't make sense to ask elsewhere.

Comment: I think the problem with this reasoning to allow questions about finding the "correct" pronunciation is that whether or not it's on-topic would be dependent on its answers. This makes it really difficult to have any sort of clear rule about which questions are fine and which aren't, especially when it doesn't have an answer yet (assuming those looking at it don't necessarily know the answer, or know there isn't one, which shouldn't be a requirement to vote to close something). Unless you're more commenting on what a good answer looks like, but this may not apply if there's just one way.

Comment: @VLAZ:  You suggest that SEQUEL morphed into SQL.  Actually, they were contemporaries for a time.  I worked on a product that used both of these languages simultaneously.  Our database vendor supported both, and their trainers and support people were very particular about being clear about which interface was being discussed at any point.

Answer (score 6):

I've compiled a list of all the pronunciation related posts that fall into the category of off-topic posts that I'm referring to, thereby allowing for a more focused discussion on the merits of individual posts.

I compiled the list by manually going through all results from this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=*pron*nc*%20closed%3ano) for answers that need closing, and from a [similar search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Newest&q=*pron*nc*%20closed%3ayes) for already closed questions. In addition, I also followed a few linked posts from the above results that looked promising. While I understand that searching for `*pron*nc*` is not the most sophisticated technique, I suspect this will yield at least a vast majority of the relevant posts.

I'm aware that releasing such a list, and soliciting feedback on them, can lead to a flurry of activity on these posts. While I expect the community to do what they feel is the right thing to do for any and all posts, I would like to urge users to avoid down-voting any of the questions or answers in the listed posts. Doing so would not really serve any of the purposes that down-voting usually does.

---

---

Also, note that several of the posts in the closed list were closed earlier today, and some more posts of this nature were closed and then deleted today as well, and as a result are not in any of the below lists. This is because the issue in question was stumbled upon by members of SOCVR, who then proceeded to close and delete some of the posts before it was realized that the scope of these closures was sufficiently broad so as to merit feedback from the community.

For completeness, here are the posts that were deleted in SOCVR before actions were ceased on pronunciation questions.

[How do you pronounce RAII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99979)

[How would you pronounce QEMU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761444)

[How does one pronounce “:=”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014297)

There may be other posts that were deleted once the issue was discovered, but these are the only ones I could find that were acted upon in SOCVR.

---

---

Based on the answers, and comments on the question and answers to this post, it appears that there are several users who would like to vote to close and/or delete some or all of the posts in the list. On the other hand, there are several users who would like to preserve some of the posts rather than deleting them. In that case, please do vote accordingly. You could also consider mod-flagging the post for a historical lock, in which case preferably add a comment on the answer explaining why you think the post should be locked. Either way, I will try to periodically update the status of the posts as and when they change.

To clarify the last point, the posts have been organized into the categories according to their status at the time of posting this answer. Posts whose status has changed after this answer was posted, are still kept in the same category to avoid confusion, but I'll add `[Closed]`, `[Deleted]`, `[Locked]`, etc. as appropriate next to those post links.

---

---

To begin, here are the questions that I'm unsure of, and might require relevant SMEs to judge whether they need editing, or should be closed, or are on-topic in their current state.

Open:

[What are the 'real' names of Haskell's Arrow operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021337)  [Closed]

[Are there human-friendly names for applicative (and friends) methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836640)  [Closed]

[Pronounceable names for scalaz operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472310)  [Closed]

[What does Google Cloud "gsutil" tool stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47945784)  [Closed]

Closed:

[Are there pronounceable names for common Haskell operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746894)

[Pronunciation of programming structures (particularly in c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565534)  [Deleted]

[What is <*> called and what does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242361)  [Locked]

[What is the accepted standard for dictating lambda expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124392)  [Deleted]

[What is JSON-P & how do you pronounce it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306344)  [Deleted]

[How do I pronounce “=>” as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022)  [Locked]

---

---

Here's a list of all the open questions that I personally think are off-topic, and should be closed, and deleted.

[How to pronounce type variables such as 'a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015413)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[What is the pronunciation of quux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60849833)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[Pronunciation of IS-IS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52350827)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[What's the correct pronunciation of “CLI”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42796210)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[When pronouncing variable-names-like-this, why do all programmers say dash instead of hyphen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372006)  [Closed]

[How are special variables with double leading and trailing underscore in python pronounced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54141161)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[In formal languages and automata “ x==>y ” is pronounced as x derives y. then how do we say x-->y?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782271)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[What is => called in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129237)  [Closed]

The following two questions are also off-topic in my opinion, but it's worth mentioning that they are actually reasonable candidates for migration to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/):

[how to pronounce recursive Rust enum lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62585217)  [Closed]  [Deleted]

[Why is ASCII named in upper-case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543965)  [Closed]

---

---

Here's a list of all the closed questions that I personally think are off-topic, and should be deleted:

[Correct Pronounciation of “XPath”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338015)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce “==” correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404944)  [Deleted]

[How do programmers pronounce “#” (number sign/hash tag/octothorpe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803779)  [Deleted]

[How does one pronounce `:` (colon / module resolution operator) in Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60789691)  [Deleted]

[What is the correct way to pronounce SCons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868781)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce the symbol -> and => in PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561288)  [Deleted]

[How to pronounce WIF (Windows Identity Foundation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142306)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce NGRX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55050371)  [Deleted]

[Pronunciation of <=> (spaceship) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54706980)  [Deleted]

[How to pronounce Google's Bazel build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366678)  [Deleted]

[How to literally read the word “MySQL”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624890)  [Deleted]

[How to pronounce a number with 1987 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836059)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce “SQLite”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655034)  [Deleted]  [Undeleted]

[“sass” vs “scss” speaking/pronouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007258)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce the new primitive “->” in NetLogo 6.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42103082)   [Deleted]

[What is the pronunciation of vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562132)  [Deleted]

[How is the symbol => pronounced in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130411)  [Deleted]

[What are the spoken names of <$> and <*>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799228)  [Deleted]

[What is the proper way to pronounce Naur in Backus Naur Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080635)  [Deleted]

[How does one pronounce “Wagner” in “Wagner-Fischer Algorithm”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25648868)  [Deleted]

[Perl how to pronounce variabls and sigil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441927)  [Deleted]

[Handsontable pronunciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060388)  [Deleted]

[Is the dot in file extensions pronounced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339939)  [Deleted]

[How do you say `\x -> y`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915918)  [Deleted]

[Python Tkinter correct pronunciation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825895)  [Deleted]

[How should I pronounce each one of these things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040735)  [Deleted]

[For english speakers, how do you pronounce 'xib'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062553)  [Deleted]

[How do you say <$> and <*> in english](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332857)  [Deleted]

[What is the assignment operator <- called when you say it out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222481)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce P/Invoke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159503)  [Deleted]

[How do you pronounce large hex numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701470)  [Deleted]

[how to pronounce “J2EE” or “Java EE”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699302)  [Deleted]

[Pronunciation of PHP str_ functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451665)  [Deleted]

[Correct pronunciation of MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972334)  [Deleted]

[What is the “->” PHP operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149)  [Locked]

[When discussing C# code, how do you pronounce '`T?`'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254877)  [Deleted]

[Best practices for pronouncing C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024254)  [Deleted]

[What is proper pronunciation for a Java 5 “Executor”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400455)  [Deleted]

---

---

If anyone finds posts of this nature that are not in any of the above lists, and it's certainly possible that I've missed some, please post a comment with a link, and I'd be more than happy to update the list.

Comment: I would suggest [meta-tag:historical-lock] instead of deletion for [What is the “->” PHP operator...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2588149/839601) Personally I would love to see it deleted but 130+ upvotes, 72K views and dosen duplicates make it a very strong candidate for lock... unfortunately

Comment: @gnat Yes, that post seems to be a reasonable candidate for a lock instead of deletion (unfortunately). However, I do question whether it's the right target for all those duplicates. The pronunciation part of the question is unfortunate, and leads to opinions. See the second sentence on the accepted answer. Instead, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502587), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856689) might be better targets. If a PHP SME agrees with that, perhaps they can swing the dupe directions as appropriate.

Comment: maybe. I only briefly checked the dupes and few of these that looked "on target" to this one, in fact somehow felt like candidates for deletion - off-topic, unsalvageable, not useful (not completely sure about this though because I only brefly checked)

Comment: @gnat It's currently protected, and the title has been edited. It could still do with some improvements, but it's much better now, and has been mod-flagged for a lock. As to the quality of the other dupes, I'll leave that to the SMEs. They're not asking for pronunciations, and as such, are not pertinent to this particular discussion.

Comment: yes, title edit made good sense, agreed. Still it would be better historically locked because of answers. When inexperienced site visitors see answer like "I call it dart" sitting at score about 60, they better also see that this is _not_ the way how one is currently encouraged to answer

Comment: @gnat Done. It's locked now

Comment: Note, the name on that question @gnat is already mentioned in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php).

Comment: Thanks for compiling the list. By looking at the questions and clicking through to several, I am now more convinced than ever that these questions should be on topic. Factual answers about word origins and designer intent let us "become better coders by sharing knowledge with each other", that's what the site is about.

Comment: @Noumenon I see what you mean. However, there are many topics that both have factual answers and help programmers, but are nonetheless off-topic. Questions on SO need to be explicitly about programming, and I don't think pronunciation of terms counts.

Comment: "it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: upon closer check of a handful remaining questions, two more look worth a historical lock are [What is <*> called...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3242361/) and [How do I pronounce “=>”...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274022/839601) Granted, these cases are less clear cut compared to one about PHP operator mentioned above because of fewer views and duplicates, but voting on them indicates certain contention among community. Lock would end this unproductive fight and prevent close/reopen wars

Comment: @gnat The `<*>` post was edited into better shape just yesterday, so I'm inclined to leave it in limbo for a bit to see which way the community leans. It does look a little more acceptable now, and there is quite a nice answer there. For the `=>` post, I still feel it should be deleted, but clearly there is some support for reopening it (note that it went through review 2 hours ago, and was voted to be kept closed 3 to 1). Still, given the views, upvotes, and previous close/reopen history, if either of those posts do get reopened, I'll flag them for locking immediately.

Comment: @gnat Done, both the `<*>` and `=>` questions have now been locked.

Answer (score 6):

I would hardly call a post with 300 views and a single answer by a deleted user with 20 upvotes and 6 downvotes "community consensus".

Questions like this are useful, because they can improve productivity by streamlining communication between developers and settle workplace arguments<sup>*</sup>, and are (albeit with a stretch) discussion about programming languages and tools, and therefore ontopic.

From the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

They're practical (you use speech), answerable (they have one or maybe a handful of answers) and are about terms you won't find outside the area of software development.

You may find them silly, but that's not a criterion that's mentioned in that help page.

They're definitely not opinion-based when the original documentation contains a declaration, or the original designer made a statement somewhere, about how a something should be pronounced.

Just leave those questions alone, there's way more questions that actually attract bad answers and don't add anything at all to the content that's on the site, and in fact, make quality content unfindable. I'm talking about the thousands of Git (not Jit) and RegEx questions that apply to a single person here. Put your effort in closing and deleting those.

<sub><sup>*</sup> I'm looking at you, front-end developers that pronounce "Vue" as "vue-wee" instead of "view", and Android developers that pronounce "Huawei" as "huey" instead of "wah-weh".</sub>

---

For the record, I've voted to undelete:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64338015/correct-pronounciation-of-xpath
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63404944/how-do-you-pronounce-correctly
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561288/how-do-you-pronounce-the-symbol-and-in-php-code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53624890/how-to-literally-read-the-word-mysql
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655034/how-do-you-pronounce-sqlite
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562132/what-is-the-pronunciation-of-vim
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130411/how-is-the-symbol-pronounced-in-scala
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060388/handsontable-pronunciation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451665/pronunciation-of-php-str-functions
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972334/correct-pronunciation-of-mysql

Either because of the amount of views and votes (a historical lock is in order there, not the deletion of useful information that's been on the site for years, maybe is linked to from other sources, which has always been taken in consideration before mass-deletions), and/or because the answers link to official resources, and/or because the answers give a proper explanation of their reasoning. I haven't read them all, but these are the ones that stood out to me based on these criteria at a quick glance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224544/discussion-on-answer-by-codecaster-can-we-speak-out-against-all-the-pronunciatio).

Comment: *They're definitely not opinion-based when the original documentation contains a declaration, or the original designer made a statement somewhere, about how a something should be pronounced.* Thus the only on-topic pronunciation questions would be those where the asker already knows that an official guidance exists? i.e. Self Q-A.

Comment: @Adriaan no, but _if_ there is an existing answer with official references, it's absolutely nonsense and outright ridiculous to retroactively close those questions as opinion-based and successively delete them. I'm all for closing off-topic questions, but I loathe the wrong close reasons from being used _just because people don't like the question, and want it gone_, especially when there's nothing wrong with said question. If you don't like a certain question but can't find a reason to close it, chances are it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Thank you very much for listing the posts that you would like to preserve, along with an explanation of why you think so. I'm not going to reverse my vote on your answer, since I still disagree with the reasoning, but the list will help the community to figure out what they think should be done about such posts.