# Please stop having opinions about things

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Running the following [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aopinion+closed%3Ayes+):

```
title:opinion closed:yes
```

currently yields 57 results. Of these, [What is your opinion on Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451619) has a historical lock. I've gone through them all, and I think the remaining 56 should be deleted, and I'd like to ask the community for help in doing so.

Note that 2 of these questions are false positives, i.e. they are not actually opinion based, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261024 is an unneeded duplicate, and [When there is no 'correct' path forward, what are Apple's/Swift's guidelines (i.e. not opinion) stating whether you should silently fail, or crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946190) is seeking recommendations, and both can be deleted.

Also, there are some posts that are fairly popular, some of which might be found by a more refined [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aopinion+closed%3Ayes+views%3A1000+votes%3A10+locked%3Ano):

```
title:opinion closed:yes views:1000 votes:10 locked:no
```

If there is disagreement about whether these, or any other posts should be deleted, or there appears to be contentious voting on any of them, please consider flagging them for historical locks.

---

---

I'm listing all the posts here, to be able to keep track of them in case any get deleted accidentally.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099457
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694628
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798496
- [Data sharing opinion requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63490801)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647060
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212408
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552849
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562630
- [Some (in my opinion) complicated stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28037877)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28307766
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482173
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107350
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857435
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807598
- [Opinion about load server and CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222925)
- [What is your opinion on Sourcegear Vault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005466)
- [What's your opinion of Castle ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516238)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56569178
- [Storing user/client passwords in database? Need your opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945280)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177799
- [What is your opinion of the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619892)
- [What in your opinion is the most abused design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541064)
- [c/c++ source code browser comparison, seeking opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842650)
- [What is your opinion on SmartBear Code Collaborator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005719)
- [ASP.Net MVC or Zend Framework. What is your opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733714)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531504
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088219
- [Ruby Community Opinion: Multiple Or Statements or a Single Include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007097)
- [Div content vs Section content, your own Opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087907)
- [Cross browser E2E testing - worth it? I need experienced opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473621)
- [Need expert opinion regarding tables structure in Parse.com app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993484)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715039
- [Designing mobile site for large site, need your opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252562)
- [What is your opinion of the Telerik Extensions for MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864804)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63163487
- [Opinion on a program that reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211788)
- [Opinion for a suitable programming language for Neural Network brain of a Robot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975496)
- [Angular 2 how to work with the model - your opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471734)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311750
- [I need people's opinion on how to update a ClickOnce application through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463975
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065421
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198115
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931664
- [Opinion: Could mruby run on little embedded gadgets, arduino due, teensy 3.0, or similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390432)
- [What do I need to program in ironpython? and what's your opinion of ironpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003713)
- [looking for opinion: Replaying production http requests into a test environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544283)
- [Opinion on how to use JavaScript ajax based likes for AJAX loaded content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63595506)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173578
- [Opinion on best Data structure for sorting Objects by type, which are non-sequential Integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23258930)
- [The reason for Ruby's <opinion>odd</opinion> default Hash.new([]) behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898385)
- [javascript formatting opinion: ' vs "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951267)
- [Your opinion on declaring constants inside methods...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676849)

---

---

Note that I'm not asking for any action at all on open posts, e.g. posts in this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aopinion+closed%3Ano):

```
title:opinion closed:no
```

which yields 290 results. There are enough false positives in this list, as well as posts that can be salvaged with some editing, that addressing these posts is beyond the scope of this request.

Finally, and for no particular reason other than I think it's fun, here's a question asked by Jon Skeet in this list:

[What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760)

Comment: That is just your opinion ...

Comment: I saw the title and got confused for a sec ;)

Comment: I was trying to be witty, but now it looks like click-bait :p

Comment: [Your opinion on declaring constants inside methods…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676849/your-opinion-on-declaring-constants-inside-methods) was answered by a legend. While none of these would be OK today, some of those are very good advice from experts. Removing them all from the site would be losing something valuable. Keeping them around would not do any harm whatsoever.

Comment: @Scratte Actually, while the answers are not bad at all, all that material is covered more comprehensively in posts like [How many and which are the uses of “const” in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455518). Perhaps some of the answers could be migrated to the appropriate posts?

Comment: You're asking users to put their delete votes on all of these posts. Why is that so important? What harm is this/all of those posts doing?

Comment: @Scratte It's just a very small step towards the goal of cleaning up SO. I'm mostly hoping that users who wouldn't otherwise use their delete votes will do so here, as most of these posts won't take any time to evaluate, and are very easy to find.

Comment: I just want to say this tho: opinion based questions tend to attract answers that recommend something. These usually have fact in them, no? For instance, a question titled, "Should I do _x_?" will attract a few answers that go, "yes, because [why]". We should downvote the answers that just say yes.

Comment: When you say "cleaning up", I see "Destroying value". [access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) says "Closed questions that are of no lasting value whatsoever should be deleted". That is not true for these posts.

Comment: @10Rep All theses posts are closed. None of them attract Answers.

Comment: @Scratte I know that, just talking in general.

Comment: @10Rep I'm not sure how it's relevant. This post is explicitly asking to delete specific posts that are already closed and that are not harmful.

Comment: @Scratte I'm afraid a general discussion about which posts should be deleted, and when opinion based questions have value, is beyond the scope here, and has been discussed on meta before. However, if there are any posts here that you think have value, then as mentioned in the question, please consider flagging them for locks.

Comment: @cigien I'm afraid that is not possible for me. I don't have enough flags. Your delete request is just humongous. I can't save any of these posts. I can only ask users don't delete them in the first place.

Comment: @Scratte Not on your own perhaps, but instead, you could post an answer listing the posts that you would like to preserve (because they have some value), and ask other like minded users to take the actions you think appropriate, similar to how I have requested users to take certain actions.

Comment: @cigien You and I both know the deal here. They will all get deleted now. Posting a list to ask for some not be deleted is just pointless. They will not get locked, and those who want to keep them cannot un-delete them.

Comment: @Scratte No, it's not. If you think some questions have value, prove it. Most users don't just delete because they're asked to. Not to mention that if a post has good value to begin with, it's very likely that it has a couple of answers with a good number of upvotes, which would make it need more delete-votes.

Comment: @Scratte I disagree. I asked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402796) question, where I basically advocated deletion of about 30-40 posts. Based on community feedback, 3 of those posts are now locked. So it's certainly not entirely pointless.

Comment: @41686d6564 Nobody has proven that they don't have value. And as you can see from this comment trail, my style of writing isn't very convincing to people. The odds are stacked. And saving just 10% spending hours to advocate seems like a loosing game. 90% will be lost anyway.

Comment: @Scratte On the contrary. All of those posts have been closed already, most of them with the "opinion based" reason, which is already lot of evidence that the posts don't have much value.

Comment: @cigien No. That a post is closed for any reason, doesn't mean it has no value. That is a false assumption. It's like saying: All closed posts should be deleted.

Comment: @Scratte True, but that's not what I said, or meant to imply. Definitely closed posts *can* have value. I just said that a post being closed is *evidence* that it doesn't have value.

Comment: A rare downvote from me. Please let the community decide, everyone has the freedom to ask, make mistakes, get downvoted, learn, and improve

Comment: @HammanSamuel I take it you're saying that posting a list of questions and suggesting deletion was a bad idea? If so, could you give me some suggestions on how to discuss this specific topic? I'd be happy to edit the question to make it more useful, and inclusive of community opinion.

Comment: @cigien I think they are trying to say that we shouldn't be doing this at all. I personally am split, because some posts do need to be deleted, but not **_this_** many.

Comment: The meme-compliant version: *[Well, you know, that's just like, your opinion, man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0aDEvmf5u0&t=2m43s)*

Comment: @scratte I don't see any 'legends' as answerers on that question. But that aside, *who* answered a question is pretty much 100% irrelevant. If we're going to save an answer, it has to be because the answer is good, not because the author of the answer is a 'legend' according to someone.

Answer (score 43):

Please stop doing keyword searches and deleting stuff that's been on the site for 5-10 years. The time and effort spent on those 50-odd posts is better spent on helping users that are posting questions *now*.

Removing old stuff has no benefits at all, other than giving the deleters a good feeling. Removing 50, 500 or even 5.000 or 50.000 (that's 0.2%) questions is not making a significant dent in the **[20.5 MILLION questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/)** we have on the site. It has **no single use whatsoever**, and you're actually actively making the Internet and the site a worse place by removing relevant information. What should be deleted are new non-questions, spam and other garbage, but any question that contains any programming-related information whatsoever, especially when "grandfathered in" (i.e. lots of views, votes, answers or time) should be left alone - unless they are overtaken by time and actively harmful (like the Favorite Programming Books / Tutorials for language X lists).

Deleting old questions because they are off-topic today is a waste of time and resources that should be better spent on helping people who are currently active on the site. If you organically encounter one and think it should be removed, cast your vote and let the queues and community do the rest - do not actively search for them, and do not gather mobs to do so.

And no, [I didn't like the previous witch hunt either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402846/266143), where at least a dozen on-topic posts with definitive value were deleted.

Comment: Thank you, once again, for voicing your opinion in an answer, I appreciate it. I understand your point about it being a waste of time, but this is entirely optional. No one is under any obligation to spend any time, or their delete votes on any of the questions. Also, regarding the reference to the previous post, as far as I can tell none of the posts that you claim have "definitive value" have been undeleted. Which suggests that their value might not be as clear as you're implying.

Comment: @cigien What is the point of the first two sentences in that comment? Were you trying to be ironic by talking about an opinion?

Comment: @cigien I'm not going to go down into that psychological argument. In my experience, people are eager to close and delete stuff, but less so to undelete and reopen. It's like they feel like they're held more accountable for the latter. After all, once closed or deleted, very few people see those posts and challenge these actions.

Comment: What do you mean deleting old questions has no benefits? I strongly disagree. We really should be focusing more attention on old questions. Deleting some of them is a very good way to keep the site clean and searching for them is a time well spent. True that some of these posts might still be valuable, but that is why Cigien has asked us to evaluate them on Meta.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Sorry, I'm not trying to be ironic at all. The comment is in reference to the post that is linked in the answer, where I had responded to one of CodeCaster's comments by asking them to write an answer with a suggestion of what users should do instead, and why. They did so, and have now posted an answer here that is similar. I'm just thanking them for that, since it's easier to respond to an answer than comments.

Comment: @Dharman _"Deleting some of them is a very good way to keep the site clean"_ - hard disagree. Removing 50, 500 or even 5.000 or 50.000 questions is not making a significant dent in the **[20.5 MILLION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/) questions** we have on the site. It has no single use whatsoever. What should be deleted are new non-questions, spam and other garbage, but any question that contains any programming-related information whatsoever, especially when "grandfathered in" (i.e. lots of views, votes, answers) should be left alone. Deleting those is a waste of time and resources.

Comment: @CodeCaster Then we should prevent new questions from being asked and clean up the existing ones. What's the point in having tons of questions if no one is moderating them? We only want to keep the really useful questions and answers. There is abosuletly no reason to keep the ones that are not a good fit for the site or are not useful to anyeone. It is our responsibility to keep the site clean. New questions are a problem because there is too many of them, but that does not mean we should ignore old questions.

Comment: @Dharman old questions just sitting there are harming nobody, apart from backup tapes.

Comment: People are finding mostly old questions through Google search. These are the questions that receive most traffic. New questions need to get a foothold first and we still have time to work on the new questions. Let's focus on the ones that are prominent in searches.

Comment: Old questions are hurting people looking for information. This is one of the main reasons why I even contribute to the site. I am annoyed with the amount of garbage thrown at me when searching for something. I barely never find the new questions

Comment: @Dharman please explain (in an answer of your own, not here in comments) how relevant information is actually hurting people. What _I_ find hurting myself when I search the web, is the ten gazillion regex and Git questions whose answers are catered to one OP and one OP only, without any explanations but just "paste these commands" or "paste these hieroglyphs". Not questions about pronunciations or experts opinions where they explain why something is a good idea or not.

Comment: I agree. I feel it's worth pointing out likewise that moderating new questions *today* prevents bad questions from becoming old ones *later*. It's really, really important to curate current, modern content now so that the archive remains as clean as possible later. If the trade-off from curating the old is less curating of the current, it's not worth it.

Comment: "The time and effort spent on those 50-odd posts is better spent on helping users that are posting questions now." - disagree heavily. Most new questions are garbage and while SO pushes "helping" individual users, a huge amount of people care more about building a valuable knowledge repository than a help site. Thus cleaning up old garbage so that it stops cluttering google search results is a very valuable use of time. Each single question counts here because each of those garbage questions could be the one that pushes a relevant question off the first page of search results.

Comment: @l4mpi no, the 50-odd questions about pronunciation and opinions on design do not push other results off of search results. This utopian, unrealistic image of a "clean repository" needs to go. The Internet is not a book with a finite amount of content.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, garbage questions do indeed push other questions off of the 5 posts google shows for SO searches - source: my everyday google use. The specific pronounciation questions might not be the worst offenders, but they're not relevant to any technical searches, and I guarantee you they're indexed by google and show up as false positives for some searches. Regarding a completely "clean repository", that's unrealistic as long as people can ask new questions. But perfection isn't required here, and any cleanup is valuable even if we can't clean up _all_ of the garbage.

Comment: @l4mpi if your motivation for removing such posts is that they are polluting your search results that have nothing to do with the subjects of said posts, the burden of proof is on you. Feel free to post an own answer with proof; otherwise, leave those questions alone.

Comment: @l4mpi in comparison, some example questions that actually pollute search results and make finding relevant hits impossible: [winforms numeric only input site:stackoverflow.com (3850 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=winforms%20numeric%20only%20input%20site:stackoverflow.com), [asp.net core iformfile null site:stackoverflow.com (2890 hits)](https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+core+iformfile+null+site%3Astackoverflow.com). Those are great candidates for editing, making a canonical Q&A, closing as duplicate, and so on. But nooo, hitting Close and Delete is way easier.

Comment: here's a formal proof: axiom 1) SO questions are crawled by google; axiom 2) crawled pages show up in searches => from (1) and (2) follows that those questions pollute search results. Furthermore, implying that garbage shouldn't be cleaned up because there's other garbage is a fallacy. Nobody is stopping you from cleaning up asp questions, so why stop others from cleaning up other things? I don't know asp and thus I couldn't reliably judge which questions should be deleted or make sense as a canonical. I can cleanup other things however, and will do so regardless of your opinion of usefulness.

Comment: @l4mpi by that logic we should delete all questions, because otherwise nobody can find anything, as all irrelevant posts push all other relevant posts out of the search results. The truth is that when people search on certain keywords, they get results relevant to those keywords. Trust me, Google has 22 years of experience in this, they kinda know what they are doing, search-wise. I do not find (all of) the questions we're talking about here (and in the pronunciation question) garbage, and therefore at least not all of them should be deleted in my opinion.

Comment: @l4mpi as for my "it's not worth it" argument, I refer you to the first and third paragraph in my answer, and to summarize: it is not beneficial to anyone but the deleter to delete old posts that are upvoted and viewed much, and only to feed their false feeling of "cleaning up the site". I find it egotistical to let that feeling go above the benefit of all other visitors that will potentially read that info. Why deprive them of relevant programming knowledge, just because you don't deem it "clean" enough? Enforce the rules on new posts but leave old posts with many views and votes alone.

Comment: Well, though I agree with the request ('please stop keyword searching for stuff to remove'), I have to -1 this because you repeatedly make a false statement with much conviction and bold for emphasis.

Comment: @CodeCaster Re 1st/3rd para: you don't get to decide what other people do. Only part I'm somewhat agreeing with is "don't gather mobs", and even that would depend on the specific case. Re all else: obviously we have different standards of what we call garbage. The "deprive" part is laughable in the context of posts like "how to pronounce sqlite" though. If you think specific questions are valuable and should be kept around, by all means make your case for them, but that's no reason not to clean up the rest.

Answer (score 6):

If the suggestion is to have some kind of regex filter check analogous to how "problem" is meant to be a regex filter check for the word "opinion", I think I'd be okay with this.  At the bare minimum, it would put a lid on people who are explicitly fishing for opinions or opinionated conversations.

<sup>Also, can we have a moment to just...revisit some of the historically locked questions?  That one from Jon Skeet doesn't even seem to be all that valuable even today.  It was just...put in resin.</sup>

Comment: Oh, I wasn't even suggesting something like that (though that sounds interesting). I'm simply asking for the community to consider casting delete votes on the listed posts if they want. Is that not clear from the question? Revisiting historical locks sounds great by the way :)

Comment: Deleting the questions sound like effort because if they have over a threshold of upvotes, it could require *a lot* of delete votes.  Maybe a mod could step in and handle this exception.

Comment: Well, that would be amazing. I'll edit the question to suggest that, thanks.

Comment: Historical lock exists to preserve content that may have been acceptable at one point. While some historically locked questions need to be deleted, some just shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @10Rep:  Why not?  When the value doesn't exist anymore, what's the point of keeping it around?  Nostalgia?

Comment: @Makoto the same can be said about the MSE post on StackOverflow Memes. That has no value, but does that mean it should be deleted? Or rather, will it be deleted?

Comment: @10Rep:  You'd need a stronger argument to remove things like that from Meta, since Meta sites aren't meant for curating the site, they're meant to discuss/facilitate circumstances that have come about because the site is being curated (and memes definitely come up during curation).  But honestly - a 250K question asking about controversial programming opinions...these days that'd just qualify as a blog post and we'd move on from it.  No reason to keep it here where we expect and demand question and answer quality.

Comment: @Makoto I actually understand your point, but one thing: If the question was deleted, wouldn't jon skeet lose a lot of reputation? I know SO isn't all about fairness, but it just doesn't seem fair.

Comment: @10Rep I think Jon will survive ;) Besides, it's a CW, so I don't think it matters.

Comment: Then I'm all for it!

Comment: Ugh, a regex block on keywords? Pardon me, but have you lost your dang mind?

Comment: @CodyGray:  I suppose I'm not going to fuss over the details.  I'd rather they tried something rather than nothing to address this issue.

Comment: So you'd rather we start fussing over people's "opinon", or perhaps people's "oponion"? Haven't you just created a new porblem?

Comment: @CodyGray:  I'm going to interpret your pessimism here as "lacking follow-up" with the sense that, just because something to detect the word "opinion" in the question exists, that doesn't mean that question askers will get the hint, nor will Stack Exchange actually add teeth to warnings like that when it comes to asking questions.

Comment: No, it's more just the the "clbuttic" problem. There are fully legitimate uses of the word "opinion" in questions. The mere appearance of that word doesn't mean that I am asking the type of opinion-based question that Stack Overflow intends to prohibit. Regex-based filters do not, in my opinion, solve any problems. It's not about the follow-through or the error messages. It's about the false positives. As much as I complain about reviewers who trigger on keywords, having the *system* trigger on keywords is even worse.

Comment: The regex block that the site really needs is 'best practice' in titles.