# Where should I ask a question about programming / code etymology?

Tags: discussion, scope

Etymology, or the history/origins of words/phrases, probably doesn't fall within the definition of a coding problem per se.

Is there a way to ask about it on Stack Overflow, or another Stack Exchange site?

If the language has functions/methods named in English, perhaps [English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), but I haven't tried and don't know how well it would go down. Especially if the term in question isn't a word (e.g. `|>`).

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331293/earliest-use-of-pipe-in-programming) is one I asked previously - it had score -3 from 15 views when I asked this meta question, although it also had a dead link (now corrected) which might not have helped its case.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but it's related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266739 The primary objection against pronunciation questions is that it's opinion based, which is less applicable for etymological questions at least.

Comment: I think there are plenty of questions along the lines of "where did this language feature come from", which are fine. Can you be more specific with your question?

Comment: @SteveBennett [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65331293/5783745)'s one I prepared earlier. It's score is -3 from 15 views. Which was what prompted the meta question

Comment: @stevec If you have a concrete question you can refer to, that's definitely something you can add to the question. You can make it clear that you're asking about this in general, and the `|>` question is just an example.

Comment: @cigien okay, will do. Also I just realised the initial question had a faulty youtube link, so perhaps that helps explain its poor reception. Darn chrome AdBlock.

Comment: I really don't know these communities so I'm not sure it is really a good fit there, but I just read [this Q/A](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/133386/is-there-any-reason-why-the-modulo-operator-is-denoted-as) on a sister site from HNQ, which seems to fall in the same category and which links to [this other Q/A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294297/in-what-programming-language-did-the-use-of-the-percent-sign-to-mean-modulo) on yet an other site. (Ps: not saying it's off-topic for here, just pointing out where you might find better experts)

Comment: @Kaiido good find. The modulo one is quite similar, and the history tag is encouraging too

Comment: On regular Stack Overflow, [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170415) seems very pertinent, insofar as it focuses in on the Help Center's guidance (from https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) that *"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**"*. Being curious about something is not an "actual problem". cc: @SteveBennett

Comment: These don't belong on SO. These are not practical programming questions, they are about the history of programming. "Something to do with software" doesn't make it on-topic. PS If you post somewhere where research should be done & reflected to avoid closure or downvotes, you should have researched & reflected it. And there is a lot of information including books about programming languages & their history out there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not sure I see a problem with users asking questions just because they're curious. So long as the question is answerable with facts, I think it can be useful and should be allowed. I say this partly as a frequenter of the [tag:language-lawyer] tag, where a majority of the questions are not based on "*practical problems that anyone faces*". I certainly don't think that makes those questions off-topic.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ok, so that very old answer references a "FAQ" that includes this quote about "actual problems" - but where is that text now? Honestly this question seems to fit fine within https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic under "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask is still up in the Help Center as authoritative documentation. The rules are specific about how they interact; they're not all ORed together.

Comment: Questions about the meaning and origin of syntax expressions would probably elicit a lot of opinionated answers or speculation. On the other hand if you ask for credible, official sources, it might work but wouldn't be very interesting in my opinion.

Comment: Pretty much any mainstream programming language is going to be in English so it should be OK to ask about on English.SE if you're asking about English parts of a programming language or the etymology of the word itself.

Comment: I don't think English.SE has any relevance for a question about the origin of a programming language feature, especially not one like `|>`.

Comment: talking about programming / code *entomology* is definitely on topic here though

Answer (score 37):

The fact that the question had several downvotes at first and now has close votes shows that it's questionable at least for Stack Overflow.

But the question would be solidly on-topic for [Retrocomputing Beta](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), as it involves computing history. See for example:

- [Origin of “tarball”](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7646/462)
- [Where does this esoteric Pascal operator come from?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3150/462)
- [Where and when did the `0x` convention for hexadecimal literals originate?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/15897/462)

Comment: It is questionable on Retrocomputing, since it might simply be about a too new operator to fit. Tarball, Pascal and 0x are all questions about last century, |> seems to be much newer. maybe even less than a decade old.

Answer (score 35):

While I believe some theoretical questions about programming languages *can* be on-topic for Stack Overflow, we do have the requirement that your question be "a practical programming problem". That leaves out questions which are merely of historical interest about etymology, origins, etc., including [this specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331293/earliest-use-of-pipe-in-programming).

It is somewhat unfortunate that these questions don't belong on Stack Overflow, since I do *like* them and often find them interesting. Fortunately, I think there *is* a place on the Stack Exchange network where they can be asked and answered (assuming, that is, that they are reasonably scoped and that they have a specific answer—i.e., that you're not just reminiscing).

If it's a programming-specific term or operator, I definitely wouldn't ask on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). Programming languages are not English.

The first place I thought of to migrate your question was [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). [Laurel had the same thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65331293/earliest-use-of-pipe-in-programming), and suggested several similar questions that were recently asked on Retrocomputing. [This question about the use of "auto" in C](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/why-is-the-auto-storage-class-specifier-included-in-c) has also been in the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) recently, and is a comparable example of programming-language history questions being well-received on Retrocomputing. **I checked with a moderator over on Retrocomputing, and they agreed that your question would be on-topic and welcome there, so I've gone ahead and migrated it.**

In the future, I think one should definitely consider Retrocomputing as a place for these types of questions, but do be sure to read [their Help Center](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first, before actually posting.

Answer (score 31):

I've seen stuff like that on the [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Examples:

> [Is there any reason why the modulo operator is denoted as %?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/133386/129635)
>
> [Why isn't there a .= operator? (or ->= etc)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/28874/129635)
>
> [Why are strings immutable in some languages?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/50530/129635)